# How deal with redirects in Wikipedia dump?

Tags: mysql, sql, wikipedia

I have successfully imported the enwiki-latest-pages-articles-multistream.XML page into MySQL using [this guide](https://www.xarg.org/2016/06/importing-entire-wikipedia-into-mysql/).

When I lookup the text for a page (process described [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Page_table)), it will often be `#REDIRECT [[some_page_name]]`. The only way I know of to follow this redirect is by searching through all page titles for `some_page_name`. Not only is this time consuming but sometimes there are multiple articles under the *exact* same title name!

I'm considering just removing all redirect pages from the database.

But before I do, is there a better way to handle these redirects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you want to determine what is the target of the redirect. Right?. If yes, then you can get it using this query:

```
select rd_title from redirect
inner join page
on page_id = rd_from
where page_title like "some_page_name"
```

The rd_title is the target page of the redirect.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but I found out that my Wikipedia database is corrupted and so I only have ~10% of the articles and lots of tables are empty (redirect is one of them). I've tried using MWDumper to import the XML dump into MySQL several times but each time the database has gotten corrupted. I've also tried re-downloading and re-unzipping the original bzip file. So while I'm unable to check your answer personally, I'll mark it right because it probably is. Regardless, thanks for the help.

Comment: Ah!. This problem happen with me before. I tried to import English Wikipedia database to a MYSQL database, and every time the database imported is not completed. Then I find out that this happen because of an error happen when importing. Usually, this error is: "Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'". The easiest way to solve this is to edit the code of mwdumper using any IDE, you will find there is a query in file "SqlWriter.java" in line 223, edit it to be like "INSERT IGNORE INTO". This will solve the problem. Also, it will help if you remove the primary key from page_id in page table.